# Java Type Mismatch?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

Okay so I had to create a program which is a parking ticket simulator. I compiled it and for the most part it works, except for this small dumb error I get which is a type mismatch. It's a lot of code so I'll just give the class which the error is:

KNW_PoliceOfficerClass

```
public class KNW_PoliceOfficer 
{ 
  private String name;
  private int badge;
  private static double ticket;

      public KNW_PoliceOfficer() 
      {

      }

      public KNW_PoliceOfficer(String poName, int poBadge) 
      {
        name = poName;
        badge = poBadge;
      }

      public String getName() 
      {
        return name;
      }
      public int getBadge() 
      {
        return badge;
      }

      static KNW_ParkingTicket search(KNW_ParkedCar car, KNW_ParkingMeter meter) 
      {
        int time = KNW_ParkedCar.getMinutes() - KNW_ParkingMeter.getMinPurchased();

        if(KNW_ParkedCar.getMinutes() > KNW_ParkingMeter.getMinPurchased()) 
        {
          if(time <= 60) 
          {
            ticket = 25;
          }
          else 
          {
            ticket = 25 + (10 * (time/60));
          }
          return ticket;
        }


      }
```

KNW_ParkingTicketClass

```
 public class KNW_ParkingTicket 
{
  private KNW_ParkedCar vehicle;
  private KNW_PoliceOfficer copster;
  private double fine;
  private int minutes;
  private double firstFine = 25;
  private double moreFine = 10;

  public KNW_ParkingTicket(KNW_ParkedCar car, KNW_PoliceOfficer cop, double guyFine, int mins) 
  {
   vehicle = car;
   copster = cop;
   fine = guyFine;
   minutes = mins;
  }

  public void getTotalFine() 
  {
   int  time = KNW_ParkedCar.getMinutes() - KNW_ParkingMeter.getMinPurchased();

   if(time <= 60) 
   {
    fine = firstFine;
   }
   else 
   {
    fine = firstFine + moreFine * (time / 60);
   }
  }

  public double getFirstFine() 
  {
   return firstFine;
  }
  public double getMoreFine() 
  {
   return moreFine;
  }
  public KNW_ParkedCar getVehicle() 
  {
   return vehicle;
  }
  public KNW_PoliceOfficer getCopster() 
  {
   return copster;
  }
  public int getMinutes() 
  {
   return minutes;
  }
  public double getFine() 
  {
   return fine;
  }


 }
```

And here is what the error says:

```
 File: C:\Users\Kyle Welch\KNW_PoliceOfficer.java  [line: 46]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to KNW_ParkingTicket
```

Any help to this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Which line? Show the full error message please.

Comment: There's a lot wrong in that code, including mis-use of static, calling methods as if they're static when they should be instance.... you're not using your method parameters at all.... time to re-write from scratch perhaps.

Comment: You declare `ticket` in `KNW_PoliceOffice` to be a `double`, and in your `search` method you say you are going to return a `KNW_ParkingTicket` but you actually return `ticket` which is a double.

Comment: `search` apparently returns a Ticket, but you're returning `ticket` which is a double.

Comment: The error would certainly reference a specific line of code.  Go to that line of code.  What are the variables on that line?  What are you trying to do on that line?  Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: `"...and for the most part it works,"` -- which is like saying "almost pregnant". Either it works or it doesn't.

Comment: *cannot convert from double to KNW_ParkingTicket* Looks like plain English to me.  What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: [@JoeC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with `ticket` parameter, you have defined it in this way : `double ticket;`

in the `KNW_ParkingTicket` method, you can see the full method with parameters here :

`static KNW_ParkingTicket search(KNW_ParkedCar car, KNW_ParkingMeter meter)`

it needs to return a type of `KNW_ParkingTicket` but you are returning a `double` named `ticket` in it :

`return ticket;`

Comment: Would you mind showing me how this can work? I would appreciate it!

Comment: Careful Mohsen -- I suspect that we have a [help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) here.

Comment: @KyleWelch i'm not responsible to code for you, i only answered the op which is why that exception happened !

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter yep ! you are right, i'm not gonna answer anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `search` method should return `KNW_Parking_Ticket` but you return `ticket` which is a `double`.

Answer (score -1):

search method in NW_PoliceOfficer class  return type is KNW_ParkingTicket but you are returning double change the method  search method return type to double.

**Try this:**

static **double** search(KNW_ParkedCar car, KNW_ParkingMeter meter){
int time = KNW_ParkedCar.getMinutes() -KNW_ParkingMeter.getMinPurchased();

if(KNW_ParkedCar.getMinutes() > KNW_ParkingMeter.getMinPurchased()) 
        {

```
      if(time <= 60) 
      {
        ticket = 25;
      }
      else 
      {
        ticket = 25 + (10 * (time/60));
      }
      return ticket;
    }
```